# Accurate way to detect rendering speed

Tags: rendering, render, p2p

I'm currently brainstorming for an idea of mine that involves a p2p render farm, somewhat like renderfarm.fi but in the difference that you pay for the service and contributors to the processing pool get paid. 
Currently renderfarms measure price based on GHZ/h, but when the computers rendering are untrusted is there a good way to measure the equivilant GHZ/h of a computer, considering the computers could be partially loaded with other programs slowing down true time spent rendering, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Because your worker process can ask the OS counters how much execution time they've received and that can be matched up with progress on the work package you can pay out based upon work-units-completed, but charge in GHz/h.  You know you can't trust the user's clock (or anything else for that matter), but you can verify the work units returned and approximate their computational complexity by combining the program counters from multiple peers.

You have no way to know for sure that the system is or is not particularly loaded, but you do know if work went out and came back.  However you will have to verify that the work was done correctly.  Probably means over-provisioning and running every render twice on two different machines to ensure someone isn't inserting garbage results that are faster to compute.

Good luck.  I don't know how you'll be able to beat the likes of Amazon with them charging ~$0.10 per GHz/h.

Answer (score 0):

The operating system can, and most likely will measure the actual *CPU time* taken up by the process. As such, that can be used as a measure of how much *practical time* the process itself has spent running on the machine's CPU. The CPU time doesn't get skewed in any direction due to other processes running on the background, so it's very ideal for this purpose.

The CPU time itself is the resource such rendering services sell, as such it's logical to measure it per user/client basis and then price the service accordingly by the CPU time spent by the user/client of the render farm.